# In django, can I have multiple instances of static app?

Tags: django, web-services, apache, django-staticfiles

Is it possible to have more than just one instance of the **static** app?

I have different types of resources that I might want to server from different `STATIC_URL`:

- I would like to serve CSS/JavaScript from `/static/`
- I would like to serve PDF documents from `/documents/`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are a bit mistaken about the purpose of `contrib.staticfiles`:

> In previous versions of Django, it was common to place static assets
>   in MEDIA_ROOT along with user-uploaded files, and serve them both at
>   MEDIA_URL. Part of the purpose of introducing the staticfiles app is
>   to make it easier to keep static files separate from user-uploaded
>   files.

PDF documents are probably user generated so ideally they are not stored side by side with your static files (css, js), but are uploaded to [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-MEDIA_ROOT).

And in production you have to [configure your web server](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx) to serve the directories under certain urls.

While in development however you can use `django.views.static.serve` [to serve different dirs with different url prefixes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-other-directories).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

I am using `urls.py`.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^docs/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/hdblog/docs'}),
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/hdblog/static'}),
    )
```

You should look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/?from=olddocs and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-other-directories